# tpm0 operation timed out error when trying to boot xubuntu 20.04 from usb

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I am trying to install Xubuntu 20.04 in Dell Latitude E6400 but when i choose try Xubuntu without installing i get tpm0 operation timed out error message. Enabling and disabling tpm in bios give same result Here's the video link https://1drv.ms/v/s!ArcURfYTLJjegS8PRSn-m4eKyS2Z

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the latest Ubuntu 22.04 image to get around this issue. It has a much newer kernel that seems to "know" how to handle these TPM errors.

That being said, there are two TPM options in my BIOS. One for "Activate" and another for "Enable" -- I had to set these to "Deactive" and "Disable"

Comment: Hello. Since Ubuntu 22.04 does not even exist yet this is not an answer.